# Im unable to use perspective-origin in css

Tags: html, css, perspective

i have tried to change perspective origin and its not working . Can someone explain that why it is not working or if it is working , what am i doing or understanding wrong. I have shown the html and css below.

```css
:root {
  --boxColor: #0ff7
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 50px;
  perspective: 10px;
  perspective-origin: 50% calc(50% - 2em)
} /* Im asking this line */
.scene {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.ball {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3em;
  left: -1em;
}

.cube {
  background: var(--boxColor);
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2em;
  left: -2em;
}

.floor {
  width: 10em;
  height: 0.4em;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to top right, red, blue);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.7em;
  left: -6em;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="floor"></div>
  <div class="cube"></div>
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

I am telling in reference to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdftnCDwKaU

Comment: Could you outline what you are trying to achieve? There is no reason that your perspective-origin setting should not work that I can see except it is only a very small change to the default perspective (center center) so I wonder if it would make any perceptible difference. Also the person viewing has their nose on the screen at perspective 10px, is this intentional? Perhaps if you could make your code into a working snippet we would be better able to see what is happening and so help.

Comment: I've now run the snippet in your question, both with and without the perspective-origin change and the viewer's position does change - with your setting one seems to be a bit more above the scene. Please explain in what way it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working to solve the same problem for a while now. After many shots in the dark and educated guesses I believe I know how to get your perspective-origin to move in the upward direction. Instead of 50%(50%-2em) try simply putting (perspective-origin: 50% 50%-20). Don't use "em" and put any number after the subtraction.